# pxe boot microsoft surface

Tags: linux, windows, pxe-boot

I'm wondering if anyone has ever attempted this before with a Linux PXE Server?

I've got it setup and working for pretty much every other laptop and desktop out there.

This is the first time I have attempted this and we have the official Microsoft Surface USB to LAN Adapter.

Here's my dnsmasq config:

```
interface=eno16777736,lo,eth0
#bind-interfaces
domain=netdec.lan
# DHCP range-leases
dhcp-range= eno16777736,192.168.1.3,192.168.1.60,255.255.255.0,1h
# PXE
dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,pxeserver,192.168.1.133
# Gateway
dhcp-option=3,192.168.1.1
# DNS
dhcp-option=6,192.168.1.1, 8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
# Broadcast Address
dhcp-option=28,10.0.0.255
# NTP Server
dhcp-option=42,0.0.0.0
user=nobody
pxe-prompt="Press F8 for menu.", 120
pxe-service=x86PC, "Proceed and choose your operating system", pxelinux
enable-tftp
tftp-root=/var/lib/tftpboot
log-dhcp
```

We fail to get the PXE Menu (proceed and choose your operating system) when using the above configuration, we only get the pxe menu when commenting out the following "dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,pxeserver,192.168.1.133".

In the logs I can see the following when PXE booting the surface;

```
Jun 15 14:12:15 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[17425]: DHCPDISCOVER(eth0)   c0:33:5e:74:41:65

Jun 15 14:12:15 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[17425]: DHCPOFFER(eth0) 192.168.1.34 c0:33:5e:74:41:65

Jun 15 14:12:31 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[17425]: DHCPREQUEST(eth0) 192.168.1.34 c0:33:5e:74:41:65

Jun 15 14:12:31 localhost dnsmasq-dhcp[17425]: DHCPACK(eth0) 192.168.1.34 c0:33:5e:74:41:65

Jun 15 14:12:31 localhost dnsmasq-tftp[17425]: error 8 User aborted the     transfer received from 192.168.1.34

Jun 15 14:12:31 localhost dnsmasq-tftp[17425]: failed sending     /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0 to 192.168.1.34

Jun 15 14:12:31 localhost dnsmasq-tftp[17425]: sent /var/lib/tftpboot/pxelinux.0 to 192.168.1.34
```

Here's a tcpdump when the surface is attempting to retrieve the pxelinux.0 file via TFTP. 
    15:06:29.757118 IP 192.168.1.34.sdsc-lm > 192.168.1.133.tftp: 40 RRQ
    "pxelinux.0" octet blksize 1468 
    15:06:29.758004 IP 192.168.1.133.54039 > 192.168.1.34.sdsc-lm: UDP, length 27
    15:06:29.759410 IP 192.168.1.34.sdsc-lm > 192.168.1.133.54039: UDP, length 30 
    15:06:29.782301 IP 192.168.1.34.3ds-lm > 192.168.1.133.tftp: 32 RRQ
    "pxelinux.0" octet blksize 1468

Is this really simple and I have missed something or is it just not possible?

Thankyou guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Surface is an UEFI only device; you won't ever be able  to boot pxelinux.0 NBP (which is BIOS only) on that device. That's why you cannot see the booting menu.

If you want to PXE a Microsoft Surface you need something like [Serva](http://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) able to automatically PXE boot/install UEFI and BIOS clients. (I'm related to Serva development)

Comment: Pat, how can I add UEFI support to the linux pxe server?

Comment: I have had a play around with Serva, it's not really what we're looking for, we don't want to be running multiple environments and want to move it away from running on a windows based server.

Comment: `>how can I add UEFI support to the linux pxe server?` this does not have an easy answer; basically your dhcp depending on the client architecture provides the corresponding NBP, and the NBP chainloads to the corresponding bootloader. In a multi-asset when offering Windows OSs you also need to deal with the BCD creation and all thta stuf

Comment: `>want to move it away from running on a windows based server` well there's not a Linux based PXE server today doing what Serva does. I could recommend SCCM or MDT but they are also Windows based. I could mention FOG or even Clonezilla but they are HDD image based solutions.

Comment: Pat - I understand for the linux pxe server to serve UEFI devices I need bootx64.efi - where can I obtain this?

Comment: Seperate question, the problem I had with Serva was that it was getting stuck on the following when loading a Windows 7 ISO: bootmgfw.efi                                            Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `>to serve UEFI devices I need bootx64.efi` this is a big misunderstanding; `bootx64.efi` is a "generic" name that can gotten when renaming syslinux,grub,ipxe,etc UEFI agents... then you need a correctly tuned UEFI boot manager; also not an easy task these days. The last versions of syslinux it includes syslinux.efi but til today it cannt chainload efi images then you cannot install windows. iPXE is a different world good for experimenting bad for working, your only choice could be Grub.

Comment: `Serva was getting stuck when loading a Windows 7 ISO: bootmgfw.efi` if Serva gets stuck when loading bootmgfw.efi you might have a network issue, or a client with old firmware, etc. Also for UEFI compatibility reasons (old clients not implementing the UEFI standard correctly) Serva includes 3 Boot Manager Modes; try i.e. BMM=2; You should probably add a new question with this issue if you want.

Comment: Created a seperate question, not sure where I amend the BMM setting.