# PXE Boot serva windows

Tags: linux, boot, pxe-boot

Created as per [pxe boot microsoft surface](https://serverfault.com/questions/784216/pxe-boot-microsoft-surface/784248?noredirect=1#comment991914_784248)

Having a problem pxe booting through serva, this is for a microsoft surface.

Windows 7 image, it seems to freeze when loading 'bootmgfw.efi' although it says "OK".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Serva 3.0.0 takes the newer 'bootmgfw.efi' from all your assets. it could happen your Windows 7 provided 'bootmgfw.efi' is not new enough for correctly booting on your Surface, or your Surface needs a firmware update.
I'd do

1. Update Surface firmware
2. Add a newer asset like Windows 10 or 8.1 for Serva getting a newer 'bootmgfw.efi'
3. Try booting your client again
4. if you are still in trouble (you shouldn't as people have installed Sufaces w/Serva w/o problem) try BMM=2 setting that in the DHCP Setting TAB under the BINL set of options.

EDIT:
Please remember BMM=1 and BMM=2 require turning "off" Secure Boot, BMM=3 (Serva Pro) allows to install MS assets on UEFI devices with Secure Boot "ON"